# javax.jcr.ItemNotFoundException: node /content/my/live/copy has no child node with name someNode

Tags: aem, jcr, crx

I created a live copy in Adobe CQ. It all works fine, but suddenly I get an error when I try to do a rollout of a page that has an node representing a page property. The error is the following: 
    `ItemNotFoundException: node /content/my/live/copy has no child node with name someNode
at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.orderBefore(NodeImpl.java:1459)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.orderBefore(NodeImpl.java:1857)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.msm.impl.actions.ContentCopyActionFactory$ContentCopyAction.createCopy(ContentCopyActionFactory.java:180)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.msm.impl.actions.ContentCopyActionFactory$ContentCopyAction.doExecute(ContentCopyActionFactory.java:136)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.msm.impl.actions.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:53)
    ... 110 more`

"someNode" does not exist in the live copy, as the error says...but rollout fails in the **contentCopy** phase, so I don't understand why the node is not just simply created. It's not a problem with the indexes as I had rebuilt the index already and I get the same result.

I am using Adobe CQ version 5.6.1.
Some indication on how to debug this would also be helpful.